# JQuery only calls WCF web method a few times

Tags: c#, jquery, wcf

I have a single Visual Studio project that has the aspx default page, some jquery scripts and the .svc WCF service file. It works fine if I connect with a browser (non debug) but when I debug in VS and hit a button that calls a web method to display the server time, it works fine the first and second times but then shows the first time again and cycles through both times. If I put a breakpoint on the web method it doesn't break after the first few times.

Is this to do with the fact that they are in the same project?

Sorry, here's the JQuery function:

```
function controlOutput(outputNumber, state) {
var webMethod = "ControlOutput?DeviceIPAddress=" + adamsIPAddress + "&OutputNumber=" + outputNumber + "&State=" + state + "&vSessionID=" + sessionID;
var fullCommandURL = webServiceUrl + webMethod;
jQuery.support.cors = true;
$.ajax({
    type: "GET", //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
    url: fullCommandURL, // Location of the service
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', // content type sent to server
    dataType: "json", //Expected data format from server
    success: function (result) {//On Successfull service call
        connectionInfo = result;
        $(h2Test).text(result);
        //alert(result);
    },
    error: function (result) {// When Service call fails
        alert(result.statusText);
    }
});
```

}

And the WCF Service code:

```
    public string ControlOutput(string DeviceIPAddress, int OuputNumber, int State, Guid SessionID)
    {
        try
        {
            string ret = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff");
            AdamSocket adamSocket = new AdamSocket();
            adamSocket.SetTimeout(1000, 1000, 1000);
            bool con = adamSocket.Connect(DeviceIPAddress, ProtocolType.Tcp, 502);
            bool res = adamSocket.Modbus().ForceSingleCoil(17, State);
            adamSocket.Disconnect();
            return ret;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogEvent(null, "Application Exception", ex.Message, SessionID);
            return "Failed";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post your code so we can help you.

Comment: Can anyone help with this? I would have thought lots of people have this issue as it's quite reproducable on my system...

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the GET command was caching and so only executing a couple of times. Using POST fixed this. ;)